# Changing out a {get; set} to a SOQL Query

Tags: apex, soql

I have this Apex Class that pulls a list of all Contact List Views and passes them through to a Visualforce page. However, these list views are showing in no particular order, causing users trouble when trying to search for one particular view. I've taken over ownership of this project from someone who is no longer able to help with this, and don't know how to write this class so that the list views are alphabetized. I tried replacing part of the code with a SOQL query (commented out), but keep receiving an error. Can anyone assist in getting this list alphabetized?

```
    public class NitishContactListViewClass {

       //public List<SelectOption> 
       //listViewNames=[SELECT Name,SobjectType FROM ListView WHERE 
       //SobjectType = 'Contact' order by Name DESC];

    public List<SelectOption> listViewNames{get; set;}
    public String conFilterName{get; set;}

    public NitishContactListViewClass(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
    String q = 'SELECT Name FROM Contact LIMIT 1'; 
    ApexPages.StandardSetController ACC = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(q));
    List<SelectOption> ListViews = ACC.getListViewOptions();
    listViewNames = new List<SelectOption>();
    for(SelectOption w : ListViews ){
        listViewNames.add(new SelectOption(w.getLabel(), w.getLabel()));
    }
  //listViewNames= [SELECT Name,SobjectType FROM ListView WHERE SobjectType = 'Contact' order by Name DESC];
} 

public PageReference resetFilter() //Dummy function
{
    return null;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were on the right track on one of your attempts.

I don't think trying to get rid of the `{get; set;}` is the right approach. Rather, I think you just need to focus on getting the listviews sorted/ordered *before you start creating the `SelectOption` instances that end up being used by your page*.

Based on some quick tinkering in anonymous apex, it looks like the ordering of the list views that you're getting now (via `ApexPages.StandardSetController.getListViewOptions()`) is by the listview id (which probably correlates to the order in which they were created).

The nice thing about using `getListViewOptions()` is that it implies that it does some automatic checking to return only the listviews available to the current user. Performing that type of check yourself is *usually* possible, but I'm not sure how you'd go about doing that in this case.

Suffice it to say, I think continuing to use `getListViewOptions()` is a good idea.

Now, there are a few different ways that you could go about sorting, but given that you're working with a Visualforce constructor (I believe DML isn't allowed in Visualforce constructors) and the governor limit on the number of queries isn't likely to be an issue, I'd suggest letting SOQL do the heavy lifting.

The general idea is that we'll:

- use `getListViewOptions()` to get the listviews we should be working on
- iterate over that to grab the listview ids
- so we can feed that into another SOQL query to do the ordering
- and use the result of that SOQL query to generate the `SelectOption` instances for your page

A brief example

```java
// This is where the final result will end up
// The "{get; set;}" bit turns this variable into a property, and is what allows
//   it to be accessed from the Visualforce page 
public List<SelectOption> myListViews {get; set;}

public myConstructor(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
    ApexPages.StandardSetController mySetCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController([SELECT Id FROM MyObject LIMIT 1]);

    // We need somewhere to gather/store our Ids before we can use them
    List<Id> listViewIds = new List<Id>();

    for(SelectOption so :mySetCon.getListViewOptions()){
        // The value of these SelectOption instances happen to contain the listview id
        listViewIds.add(so.getValue());
    }

    // SOQL doing the ordering for us
    // If you want A-Z ordering, then you probably want to sort by ascending value
    for(ListView lv :[SELECT Id, Name FROM ListView WHERE Id IN :listViewIds ORDER BY Name ASC]){
        // I imagine that the Id of the listview is going to be more useful in later code
        //   than the name is, so I've used that as the "value" (first argument) of the SelectOption
        myListViews.add(new SelectOption(lv.Id, lv.Name));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Derek, thank you for helping with this! I've been able to get most of that implemented, but when I tried adding in the part that you typed as "myListViews.add(new SelectOption(lv.Id, lv.Name));", I kept receiving the error message: "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void add(System.SelectOption) from the type List<Id>"

Typed as:
`listViewIds.add(new SelectOption(lv.Id, lv.Name));`

Comment: @KristenSlack In my example, `listViewIds` and `myListViews` are separate. Apex is a "strongly, statically typed" language, so data types need to match. That `new SelectOption()` bit gets you an instance of type `SelectOption`, and needs to be added to a list of the same type (a `List<SelectOption>`). You're getting the error because the list type of `listViewIds` is `Id`, which is not compatible with `SelectOption`.